# How to verify ssh key on Gitlab.com

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I'm setting up a SSH key for the first time on Gitlab.com. I'm stuck at [verifying](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#verify-that-you-can-connect) that you can connect: `ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com`.

The `gitlab.example.com` you are supposed to replace with your Gitlab instance url but I keep getting "ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known".

I'm using the Gitlab SaaS solution and have tried various formats, such as:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com/my-workspace-name
ssh -T git@gitlab.com:my-workspace-name
ssh -T git@gitlab.com/my-workspace-name/project-name
```

What is the correct format that should work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Correct format is `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`.

`my-workspace-name` is not part of the instance url.